Special derivative of $y=|x|$ at $x=0$
When I think about a practical problem, I find that I need a very special kind of derivative. I have no knowledge of this subject, so I would like to ask help.
For example, we know $y=|x|$ is not derivable at $x=0$ in calculus. But I want a special derivative such that
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{Dy}{Dx}\Big|_{x=0} =0  \tag{1}  \\
&\left(\frac{Dy}{Dx}\right)^2\Big|_{x=0} =1   \tag{2}  \\
& \frac{D^2 y}{Dx^2} \Big|_{x=0} =0   
\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
where I use $\frac{D}{D}$ denote the special derivative.  I know (1) and (2) are  very contradictory, but please don't sneer me because this is  an exploration, and I'll explain why below.
The reason of (1) and (3) is that $x=0$ is local  minimum point of  $y=|x|$. The reason of (2) is that
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}(0^+)\right)^2 =\left(\frac{dy}{dx}(0^-)\right)^2 =1  \tag{4}
$$
Be more specific, I consider a PDE
$$
u_t = u_{xx} +u_x +(u_x)^2 -1  \tag{5}
$$
where $u=u(x,t)$.   For any fixed $t_0 \in \mathbb R$, near $x=0$, the $u(x,t_0)$  likes $y=|x|$ near $x=0$.  From a realistic point of view, the $u(0,t)$ should be non-decrease along the time $t$. Or at least, there should be series $\{t_i\}\subset \mathbb R$ such that $u(0,t_i)$ is non-decrease.  Therefore, I try to show $u_t(0,t)\ge 0$. This is why I want   (1),(2),(3).
If this problem  is difficult to explain, it will suffice to tell me which book I should read. Thanks very much.

Is your ultimate goal to prove that the solution of that PDE has $u(t,0)$ increasing? I don't see how would inventing a new derivative help you with that (as its formulated using ordinary derivatives).

I think considering the Right and Left Hand derivatives will be a good idea. $f(x)=|x|$. Now $f(0^{+})=|0^{+}|$ and $f(0^{-})=|0^{-}|$. Therefore you can surely say that $f(0^{+})=f(0^{-})$

@Winther  Yes, to prove non-decrease of   $u(t,0)$ is enough for me. Do you have idea? Thanks.

What is the initial/boundary condition to the PDE? To study this PDE I would first try to simplify it. For example if you put $u = v + \alpha x$ then the constant term vanishes if $\alpha^2+\alpha = 1$. Then you can also make the transformation $v = \log(w)$ to get something like $w_t = w_{xx} - \sqrt{5}w_{x}$ which is a much simpler linear PDE (roughly the heat equation).

@Winther  Sorry, it is not PDE. At $x=0$,  $u_{xx}, u_x$ don't exist  in the traditional sense, since near $x=0$, $u$ likes $y=|x|$. And the reason I wrote (5) is because it's true everywhere except $x=0$. But I need deal the $u$ at $x=0$. So I want a special derivative. My English and thinking are not very good, may describe this matter is not appropriate, I am very sorry.

@Winther  I've got an idea for how to do this. Take the average of the left and right derivatives. Let me try.
